# Flex getElementByName

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, getelementsbytagname

I know that there is no such function as getElementByName in Flex but I also now that you can do this["object_id"] to get the element of the application u're in.
What about getting an element inside another element?
I've tried making `element["id"]` ? But in my try-catch it always runs the "catch" part =\
So: how do I get an element inside another element just having it's id in dynamically created string form?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what kind of element you are trying to access.

1. A child display object can be accessed by calling [DisplayObjectContainer#getChildByName](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildByName%28%29):
   `element.getChildByName("name");`
2. A public variable (which could be set to also contain a child display object) can be accessed by using [bracket syntax](http://www.senocular.com/?entry=241):
   `element["name"];`

   or simply using [dot syntax](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=27191&seqNum=4):`element.name`

(where name is the name of the property you are trying to access).

Note that any instance you drag to the stage in the Flash IDE will [automatically be assigned to a public variable](http://blog.ickydime.com/2008/07/as3-notes-automatically-declare-stage.html), if you have the "automatically declare stage instances" option checked in your export settings. That is why using `this[name]`works.

Comment: I'm talking about FLEX here, no stage so. I'm also talking about UIComponents objects which does not have children, but elements. Just for information I'm working with a TabNavigator right now.

Comment: Well, that's good info - perhaps you should be adding that to your question, next time around.  Anyway, check out the info for UIComponent and *tada*: It's a subclass of DisplayObjectContainer... http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildByName()

Comment: And FYI it *does* have children.

Comment: in Flex even if you're working with DisplayObjectContainers unfortuantely it's not sure that the addChild getChild removeChild works....

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're asking for a way to get all the "elements" in a Flex application that have a certain name.

Here's an example (Flex 3):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" xmlns="*">
  <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
      private function testIt():void
      {
        var arr:Array = getDisplayObjectsByName(this, "foo");
        for each (var e:* in arr)
          trace(e);
      }

      private static function getDisplayObjectsByName(node:DisplayObjectContainer,
          name:String, recurse:Boolean = true):Array
      {
        var n:int = node.numChildren;
        var a:Array = [];
        for (var i:int = 0; i < n; i++) {
          var c:DisplayObject = node.getChildAt(i);
          if (c.name == name)
            a.push(c);

          if (recurse) {
            if (c is DisplayObjectContainer)
              a = a.concat(getDisplayObjectsByName(DisplayObjectContainer(c),
                  name, true));
          }
        }

        return a;
      }
    ]]>
  </mx:Script>
  <mx:VBox name="foo">
    <mx:HBox>
      <mx:Button name="foo" label="Test" click="testIt()" />
    </mx:HBox>
  </mx:VBox>
  <mx:Label text="Ignore Me" />
  <mx:VBox name="bar">
  </mx:VBox>
</mx:Application>
```

Here we're looking for all the elements called "foo" when the user clicks the "Test" button.

Output:

```
main0.foo
main0.foo.HBox5.foo
```

You'll notice that `getDisplayObjectsByName()` is `static`. All it does is traverse the display list (depth-first) and pick out all the objects with the specified name.

Comment: I don't have the possibility to test it now, but I thank you in advance! By the way I just want to get the "foo" element in the first level of children. So just the VBox =) I think that I just have to remove the last if statement, right? ;)

Comment: @AndreaSilvestri I've changed the name to "getDisplayObjectsByName" to reflect the fact that we're looking for `DisplayObject`s, not "elements" (like XML elements), and also added a `recurse` parameter, which is `true` by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the element in a [`Group`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Group.html), you can use this function:

```
static function getElementByName(group:GroupBase, name:String):IVisualElement {
    const child:DisplayObject = group.getChildByName(name);
    const index:int = group.getChildIndex(child);
    return group.getElementAt(index);               
}
```